# Trying to convert plain textarea input into somewhat formatted newlines

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, text, view, textarea

Here's an example of what I'm inputting into my creation form:

[image]

I'd like to somehow convert that input into actual HTML **when rendering in my view** like:

```
<p>+65 Magical Power</p>
<p>+75 Mana</p>
<p>+10 MP5</p>
```

I tried to create a helper method in the `Item` class. But it seems I cannot use the `content_tag` method in the Models or Controllers.

What would be a good way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think `<xmp></xmp>` can be used. I tried using it with simple `<p> </p>` tag but did not try echoing the input field.